# PHP sprintf() Error de argumentos al colocar una url con Whatsapp

Tags: php, sprintf

Estoy colocando una URL de Whatsapp en PHP en el siguiente código:

```
$url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=57xxxxxxxx&#038;text=Bienvenido%20a%20xxxxxx,%20estas%20interesado%20en%20el%20Tartar%20de%20Atun%20";
$link = sprintf( '<a href="'.$url.'" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="whatssapp">Pídelo ahora</a>');
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\elmandadito\wp-content\themes\online-shop\functions.php

Cuando cambio la URL por con `https://www.google.com.co` funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Por qué estás usando `sprintf` para unir las cadenas? Lo estás haciendo mal de esa manera y, además, olvidas agregar un parámetro por cada `%s` adicional que insertes en la cadena de formato (primer parámetro) e incluso los que contienen de manera involuntaria la URL.

Comment: Por ejemplo, la parte que pone `Tartar%20de%20Atun`, el formato `%20d` significa un parámetro de tipo entero que tendrá 20 cifras rellenando con espacios lo que falte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes meter la URL como parámetro `%s` de `sprintf` ya que tu URL contiene caracteres que definen el formato (zonas que contienen el carácter `%`), por lo que `sprintf` se queja de haber definido huecos para datos que no has rellenado con los parámetros correspondientes:

```
$url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=57xxxxxxxx&#038;text=Bienvenido%20a%20xxxxxx,%20estas%20interesado%20en%20el%20Tartar%20de%20Atun%20";
$link = sprintf(
  '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="whatssapp">Pídelo ahora</a>',
  $url,
  htmlspecialchars($id),
  htmlspecialchars($sku),
  htmlspecialchars($cantidad)
);
```